# askdifferent.com redirection to apple.stackexchange.com adds an extra / in the URL

Tags: bug, status-completed, redirection

Consider the following question on Ask Different:

> [The volume can't be ejected because it's currently in use](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/104842/the-volume-cant-be-ejected-because-its-currently-in-use)

Its URL is:

```
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/104842/the-volume-cant-be-ejected-because-its-currently-in-use
```

If we change the domain name to askdifferent.com, we have:

```
http://askdifferent.com/questions/104842/the-volume-cant-be-ejected-because-its-currently-in-use
```

This redirects us to the following URL:

```
https://apple.stackexchange.com//questions/104842/the-volume-cant-be-ejected-because-its-currently-in-use
                               ↑
```

There is an extra `/` in the redirected URL at the location indicated by the ↑.

The same issue shows up at least for crossvalidated.com vs. stats.stackexchange.com  and presumably for any other sites for which vanity URLs exist (which is why this is posted here rather than on a local meta).

Comment: Let me take a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be fixed in the next prod build. Thanks for bringing it up!